# ruby net-scp folder copy recursively is failing due to ArgumentError: unknown directive: "0664 13508

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scp

I am trying to copy one geo to another geo the entire folder using net-scp in the Ruby programming language:

```
Net::SSH.start(geo_hostname, username, :password => password) do |ssh|
      channel = ssh.scp.download(sorce_path,dest_path, options={:recursive=> true, :preserve => true})
      channel.wait
end
```

I am getting below error:

```
ArgumentError: unknown directive: "0664 13508 csrgb_2.pl.summary\n"
```

Full stack trace:

```
ArgumentError: unknown directive: "0664 13508 csrgb_2.pl.summary\n"
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp/download.rb:118:in `parse_directive'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp/download.rb:38:in `read_directive_state'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:369:in `block (3 levels) in start_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `process'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `block in preprocess'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `preprocess'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
    from /opt/adp/projects/Etrans3/releases/20191120071753/app/workers/log_worker.rb:56:in `block in perform'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `start'
    from /opt/adp/projects/Etrans3/releases/20191120071753/app/workers/log_worker.rb:54:in `perform'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@etrans/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Below are the files inside the `sorce_path`:

```
$ ls -ltr | grep csrgb_2.pl.summary
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raj raj      4047 Nov 22 00:00 csrgb_2.pl.summary.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raj raj     13508 Nov 22 00:00 csrgb_2.pl.summary
```

Gem file:

```
gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'
gem 'net-scp', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please, paste the full stacktrace

Comment: @mrzasa updated the stacktrace

Comment: Have you tried with a port?